# Unwanted Horizontal Scrollbar appearing in IE8 in Sharepoint

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, internet-explorer-8

Having some trouble with a website. For some reason, there is a horizontal scroll-bar appearing allowing you to scroll a lot towards the right in IE8 even though there is no content there. I may have messed up with width's or margins or something, but it doesn't make sense because when I load the code outside of SharePoint it works fine, even in IE8. In SharePoint, inside a content editor web part, the code makes the horizontal scroll bar (although it doesn't appear in Chrome even with SharePoint).

The following code will hide the scrollbar for me, but you can still scroll to the right. The code just makes the scrollbar invisible.

```
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Any other solutions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2010 the main content of the page resides inside s4-workspace Div and the ribbon is kept fixed at the top. So may be you can try to give the overflow attribute to s4-workspace div.